# Is there really an Anonymous class/struct in C++?

Tags: c++, anonymous-class, anonymous-struct

I'm confused by many websites: People there refer to a `class/struct` as Anonymous when it has no name for example:

```
struct{
   int x = 0;
}a;
```

I think the example above creates an Unnamed `struct` but not an Anonymous `struct`. I think an Anonymous `struct/class` doesn't have a name nor a declarator after the close-curly brace that ends the class body and before the semi-colon that ends the class definition:

```
class { // Anonymous class
   int x_ = 0;
}; // no delcarator here
```

And of course the standard refuses such declaration above because it is ill-formed.

- `union`s can be Unnamed or Anonymous:

  ```
    union{
       char unsigned red_;
       char unsigned green_;
       char unsigned blue_;
       long unsigned color_ = 255;  
    } color;
  ```

In this example above I've declared an unnamed (but not an anonymous) union and this is similar to the class/structs above.

- A `union` can be Anonymous:

  ```
    // cannot be declared in a namespace except adding `static` before the keyword `union` which makes the linkage of the unnamed object local to this TU
    /*static*/ union{ // Anonymous union
       char unsigned red_;
       char unsigned green_;
       char unsigned blue_;
       long unsigned color_ = 255; ;
    }; // no declarator

    green_ = 247; // ok accessing the member data green_ of the Anonymous union
  ```
- Above I've declared an Anonymous `union` and the code works just fine. The reason is that the compiler will automatically synthesize an object of that Anonymous union and we can access its members directly. (although there are some restrictions).
- I think the compiler disallows Anonymous class/struct because it doesn't automatically creates an object of that type.

So are my thoughts correct? if not please guide me. Thank you!

Comment: Suppose you *could* create the type without giving it either a name or immediately declaring instances. What would you expect the code to look like, that *uses* it?

Comment: @Ext3h: No! An anonymous union is a part of the C++ standard: please take a look at this from cppreference:   https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union the part about Anonymous unnions.

Comment: I think the terms "unnamed struct" and "anonymous struct" are synonymous, at least in casual use.  If you want chapter-and-verse from the standard, you might want to consider the `language-lawyer` tag.

Comment: The downside to an unnamed or anonymous struct is that you cannot provide a constructor or destructor.  (Note, you can use `decltype(a) b; b.x = 5;`.)  I've used an unnamed or anonymous struct to implement a kluge / janky sort of *properties* fields in C++.  They didn't have to be unnamed for any particular reason, I just didn't need to name them so I didn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the terminology of the C++ standard ([N4659](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf)), only unions can be "anonymous". Neither the phrase "anonymous class" nor "anonymous struct" appear anywhere in the standard. In fact, the word "anonymous" itself appears only 44 times in the standard: 42 times followed by the word "union", and twice on its own underneath the "union" sublist of the Index.